# Insert server datetime using a SqlCommand

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a SqlCommand which inserts a datetime into column using a SqlParameter.  At present I use DateTime.Now as the value of this parameter.

I believe this will add the datetime on the user's PC which is not consistent.

How do I change this so the datetime of the database server is inserted?

EDIT:

I should have made it clear this was just for inserts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this strictly for INSERTs ? Or for updates as well?

If it's for INSERTs only, you could declare a DEFAULT constraint on your DATETIME column on the SQL Server side, and then just not insert a value from the client side - thus using the server's default.

In SQL:

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTable 
   ADD CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_YourColumn
     DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR YourColumn
```

and then in your SQL command, just don't mention the "YourColumn" and don't provide a value for it - the server will use `getdate()` to get the current date/time on the server instead.

Marc

Answer (score 6):

Don't pass in a parameter for the current date; get SQL Server to generate it.

The SQL to do what you described is `GETDATE()`, though you may want to consider using `GETUTCDATE()`, as it will behave better with respect to timezone changes (and moving the server!)

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Can a SQL Server function be specified as the value of a SQLParameter?  If not I assume the best method would be to use a default constraint as suggested in another answer

Comment: I don't think it can. Default constraint would work well if you're currently inserting directly into the table - I was assuming that this was part of a larger Stored Procedure.

Comment: +1: IMHO, this *is* the best solution. Nonetheless, if DataSets are used, the DateColumn.DateTimeMode may be used to have all users have consistent TimeZone settings (Utc, I assume). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datetimemode.aspx

Comment: @Dave: you may add the DEFAULT CONSTRAINT as marc_s suggested, or you can just call GETDATE() in your SP. In both cases you would not pass the value as the parameter to the SP.

Comment: @van: Indeed - a Default Constraint will work in either circumstance. If I already had a sproc I'd probably keep the logic in the sproc and out of the table definition, but each to their own.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  As I am using a paramterised SQL string rather than a stored proc, and this requirement is just for inserts I have accept the default constraint answer

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ga-gz_1.htm

Comment: This is for SQL 7... and it's still just a copy of Books On Line that was never updated

Answer (score 0):

In that case, don't pass a datetime value as a parameter. Instead use the GetDate() function and insert that result in the table

insert into X (Id, Col1, Col2) values (1, 'Customer1', GetDate())

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may use stored-procedure and GETDATE(),

> tableName(no: int, name: varchar(40), date datetime)

Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  AddRec
@no int,
@name varchar(40)
AS
insert into tableName
 values (@no,@name,getdate())
RETURN
```

Code to execute stored-procedure

```
SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("Your_Cn_Str");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText="AddRec";
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedue;
cmd.Connection=cn;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@no",10);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name","Foo");

cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cn.Close();
```